# Finding drugs based on gene expression data

Tags: gene-expression, drugs

I've got a list of genes and I want to assess their association with drugs based on gene expression data sets.

A comprehensive tutorial would also be helpful.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think the question needs elaborating, what drugs, what genes, what species, what disease are the drugs targeting. Without this I'm not sure the question is viable

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you can provide more information about the gene expression data set. If you have response to single drug, the general approach is to find the deferentially expressed genes with tools like [DESeq2](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/DESeq2.html), or make a heat map based on the expression of your listed genes to see the drug effect before and after the treatment. But, if you want to study the effects of combination of drugs it is necessary to consider the additive and synergistic effect of drug combinations.

Comment: I agree with this